# QUICKFIX Logon Request. Session getting disconnected.

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am trying to get messages from a message queue and forward them to some other queue using quickfix. I encounter an IllegalStateException when a message is read. Exception message is Logon did not succeed. I think the issue is with session handshake.

```
Jun 6, 2017 11:49:35 AM quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler sessionCreated
<20170606-06:18:35, FIX.4.2:FROMPAT->TOPAT, outgoing> (8=FIX.4.2☺9=80☺35=A☺34=683☺49=FROMPAT☺52=20170606-06:18:35.614☺56=toPAT☺98=0☺108=1200☺10=180☺) 
<20170606-06:18:35, FIX.4.2:FROMPAT->TOPAT, event> (Initiated logon request)
Jun 6, 2017 11:48:37 AM quickfix.Session disconnect 
iNFO: [FIX.4.2:FROMPAT->TOPAT] Disconnecting: IO Session closed
```

Comment: Debug, debug, debug, debug, debug, debug !!

Comment: Did and solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your CompIds and sequence numbers. These are the top two reasons we see login failures. Especially when setting up a new session, check you have the SenderCompId and TargetCompId the right way around, it's surprisingly easy to mix up!

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I was new to QuickFix. Solved the problem. Now that I look at it, it was a really dumb question. Thanks.